# Using RPN (Reverse Polish Notation)

Tags: c#, rpn

I've written some code to convert the following infix notation: `(A OR B) AND C` to `A B OR C AND`. I now need to be able to use this RPN to build out more objects which is used by an API provided by the application I am developing for.

The documentation provided by the application developers shows how to build out the `(A OR B) AND C` expression into their API:

```
// Create the CriteriaCollection to store the criteria for the search DTO
CriteriaCollection baseConditionCollection = new CriteriaCollection();

// Create a new CriteriaCollection for the first set of criteria within the parentheses
CriteriaCollection collectionWithinParens = new CriteriaCollection();

// Create the first two criteria, with an Or BooleanOperator on criteria1, before criteria2
Criteria criteria1 = new Criteria();
criteria1.Condition = new CriteriaCondition(new Services.Field.FieldRef()
{
    Name = "A"
}, CriteriaConditionEnum.AnyOfThese, new List<int>{ 112233, 987987 });

// Add Or BooleanOperator on criteria1.
criteria1.BooleanOperator = BooleanOperatorEnum.Or;

// Add a boolean condition as criteria2.
Criteria criteria2 = new Criteria();
criteria2.Condition = new CriteriaCondition(new Services.Field.FieldRef()
{
    Name = "B"
}, CriteriaConditionEnum.Is, true);

// Add criteria1 and criteria2 to the collectionWithinParens
collectionWithinParens.Conditions.Add(criteria1);
collectionWithinParens.Conditions.Add(criteria2);

// Set the And BooleanOperator following the collectionWithinParens
collectionWithinParens.BooleanOperator = BooleanOperatorEnum.And;

// Add the collectionWithinParens to the baseConditionCollection
baseConditionCollection.Conditions.Add(collectionWithinParens);

// Create the third Criteria
Criteria criteria3 = new Criteria();
criteria3.Condition = new CriteriaCondition(new Services.Field.FieldRef()
{
    Name = "C"
}, CriteriaConditionEnum.IsLike, "FW: ");

// Add criteria3 to the baseConditionCollection then set the DTO to the base collection.
baseConditionCollection.Conditions.Add(criteria3);
search.SearchCriteria = baseConditionCollection;
```

Have can I convert my RPN notation to the API sample posted above?

Comment: Wouldn't the RPN version of the infix `(A OR B) AND C` be `A B OR C AND`?

Comment: Sorry you're right, I read it the wrong way round. I've changed my original post.